# Error with the test after instalation cygnus-ngsi (via Docker and RPM)

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I have a problem when I execute the comand
[root@localhost cygnus-ngsi]# mvn test

Attached a  [screenshot with the problem (test)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CuTB.png)

I have the same problem when the installation has been via Docker or via RPM
I don´t Know how to fix the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Put the relevant log in the question not in a picture.

Comment: Failed to execute goal on project cygnus-ngsi: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.telefonica.iot:cygnus-ngsi:jar:1.7.0: Could not find artifact com.telefonica.iot:cygnus-common:jar:1.7.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)